# java - what is the fastest way(method) to test if double is an int and how to decide?

Tags: java, performance

how can i tell which method is better to use for my situation or faster?.
for example:-

```
public boolean isSquareNumber(){

        double nd = Math.sqrt(num); // num is a class member variable.

        if(nd == Math.floor(nd))
        {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

and this method

```
 public boolean isSquareNumber(){

        double nd = Math.sqrt(num);

        if(nd == (int)Math.sqrt(nd))
        {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Math.floor() and Math.sqrt().
both were exactly the same for this situation but how do i decide which is faster?.

Thank you for your time <3.

Comment: There seems to be some mistake in your second method. Only 0 and 1 are equal to their square root.

Comment: *"Math.floor() and Math.sqrt(). both were exactly the same for this situation"* Um...no. For instance, if `num` is `16`, `nd` will be `4` and `nd == Math.sqrt(nd)` will be false, while `nd == Math.floor(nd)` will be true. What makes you think that `sqrt` and `floor` are the same there?

Comment: @Gus it would for `nd = 1.0` or `nd = 0.0`.

Comment: realized that = )

Comment: Doesn't matter which is faster; **only _one_ is correct**.

Comment: i am so sorry , i didn't cast it to int in the sqrt() method , and i am not saying they are both the same in general , i want to know which is faster for this situation and how to decide that a method is faster in a situation.

Comment: Well, the solution that doesn't do `sqrt` twice is probably faster.  More importantly, the one that _does_ do `sqrt` twice is almost certainly **wrong**, unless your definition of a "square number" is different from the one I have in mind...

Comment: uhm... i have tested both of them , using sqrt twice does work , double saves float point for not perfect squares until it tests a perfect square , is there any docs to know which method is faster(not only for this example(talking generally)) .

Comment: @DomPierre Please fix your question, you can edit both the body and the title as needed. The title and the body don't match. For testing if a double is an integer, there's absolutely no point in using `sqrt`.

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way to test if a `double` value is an integer will be this:

```
double d = ...
if (d == ((long) d)) {
   // It is an integer
}
```

---

Note that is (theoretically) possible for `sqrt(someValue)` to produce an `double` value that is indistinguishable from an integer value, even though the true square root of `someValue` is not an integer.  As the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#sqrt-double-) states:

> Otherwise, the result is the double value *closest* to the true mathematical square root of the argument value.

So you could get a case where the "closest" double value corresponds to an integer, even though the actual square root is irrational.

---

The other point of contention is whether `Math.floor` is actually correct.

On the one hand, the narrowing cast and `Math.floor` are different:

- narrowing uses IEE 754 "rounding towards zero" mode
- `Math.floor()` returns *"the largest (closest to positive infinity) floating-point value that less than or equal to the argument and is equal to a mathematical integer"*.  In other words, it rounds towards negative infinity.

On the other hand, if we are testing a `double` value that is known to be non-negative<sup>1</sup>, then rounding towards zero and towards negative infinity are the same thing.

---

<sup>1 - Is this the case for `Math.sqrt()`?  Strictly no, since `sqrt(-0.0)` is defined to return `-0.0` ... per the javadoc.  However, `-0.0` should be treated as `+0.0` for the purposes of rounding.</sup>